# remove end-of-line comments unless quoted

Tags: regex, perl, comments

I need a Perl regex to remove end-of-line comments. I feel like I've Googled around for this and couldn't find just the right thing. Here are the details:

EOL comment is indicated using a pound sign (#)

Anything can be quoted using vertical bars (|)

So the following has a comment:

```
foo bar #baz
```

But the following doesn't:

```
foo |quoted###with bars|
```

The following has a comment and a quote that contains the comment character:

```
foo |quoted###with bars| #comment here
```

The first thing I tried was `s/#(?=[^|]*$).*$//`, which unfortunately removes quoted pounds. The next thing that doesn't work is `/#(?=[^|]*$).*$//`, because it fails on multiline quotes, like the following:

```
foo |quote begins here ##still going
        ##and it's still going| #this is a quote, though.
```

I feel like I may be able to glean something from the regex for C/C++ comments in [perlfaq6](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?), but it's too complicated for me grab just the stuff I need (don't need multiline comments;).

Can anyone provide a regex which removes EOL comments but ignores quoted comment characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

> `s/(\|[^|]*\|)|#.*/$1||''/eg`

This replaces `|...|` (including `|...#...|`) with itself, and `#...` with nothing.

Comment: Almost... doesn't cover the multiple line thing.

Comment: @NateGlenn: Sure it does; did you try it? When I tried it on `abc|def#ghi`, plus a newline, plus `klm|nop#qrs`, it only stripped off `#qrs`, because `#ghi` is inside a multiline `|...|` fragment. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: It's hard to decide what is what in source code. This regex finds the #, no matter how it's used, and removes it to the end of the line unless it's in pipes. Merely seeing a # in code doesn't mean that it's starting an end of line comment.

Comment: @briandfoy: Thanks for your comment, but I think you've misunderstood something. According to the question, any # outside of pipes *does* mean that it's starting an end-of-line comment. (You mention "source code", but the OP doesn't say anything about source code, and his/her format isn't a language I recognize.)

Comment: No, there's just incomplete information. I've seen plenty of people ask similar questions about removing comments without realizing that it's not so simple. That we don't know the type of source or its rules, other people should be aware that there can be a problem in their own use.

Comment: @briandfoy: I don't understand how you can be so confident that # can appear outside comments and quoted segments, when you literally don't even know what format you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

```
  private static int find(String s, String t, int start) {
    int ret = s.indexOf(t, start);
    return ret < 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : ret;
}

private static String removeLineCommnt(String s) {
    int i, start = 0;
    while (0 <= (i = find(s,"//", start))){ //Speed it up
        int j = find(s,"'", start);
        int k = find(s,"\"", start);
        int first = min(i, min( j, k));
        if (first == Integer.MAX_VALUE) return s;
        if (i == first) return s.substring(0, i);
        //skipp quoted string
        start++;
        if (j == first) { // ' asdasasd '
            for (int p = s.indexOf("\\'", start); p >= 0; p = s.indexOf("\\'", start)) {
                start += 2;
            }
            start = s.indexOf("'",start);
            if (start < 0) return s;
            start++;
            continue;
        }
        // " asdasdasd "
        for (int p = s.indexOf("\\\"", start); p >= 0; p = s.indexOf("\\\"", start)) {
            start += 2;
        }
        start = s.indexOf("\"", start);
        if (start < 0) return s;
        start++;
    };
    return s;
}


private static String removeLineCommnts(String s) {
    if (!s.contains("//")) return s; //Speed it up

    return Arrays.stream(s.split("[\\n\\r]+")).
            map(CommonTest::removeLineCommnt).
            collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are showing here, but you can't merely find in any context the same characters would denote the start of a comment in the right context and assume you should remove everything to the end of the line.